# Dnn labels not showing

Tags: jquery, dotnetnuke

i have a problem on my site. when i go to module settings i cannot see labels i can only see fields or dropdowns. im using dnn 6

Comment: please post what you have done

Comment: i have created my own dnn modules and uploaded them and they are working just fine but now the whole site is not showing labels :(

Comment: check file system permissions for those

Comment: are you checking in IE9?

Comment: Most probably you are missing out Text property or resource file entry, check it out

Comment: Swarnajith all browsers its doing the same

Prashant i dont mean to be blond can you tell me more on that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using Google Chrome right click on a nearby item and "Inspect Element." Look in the DOM that is shown and see if the label is indeed getting added to the page or if it is not even getting rendered. Perhaps the label is getting rendered with no text... or maybe it is a CSS class that was accidentally targeting all labels and set them to dispay:none.

Also Chrome's inspector when you refresh the page should say whether any Javascript errors are occurring. Should be a little red number indicator in the lower right.

Comment: that is the answer. thank a lot :) css on default.css was set to display:none